# How to fix the operation of a command `git flow` from a file `package.json`?

Tags: git, npm, git-flow

I'm opening this issue because:

npm is producing incorrect or undesirable behavior.

What's going wrong?

The `git flow` command from the file `package.json` does not work.

File `package.json` contains:

`json
  "scripts": {
      "s1": "git flow release start v1",
      "s2": "git flow"
  },`

How can the CLI team reproduce the problem?

The command `npm run s1` does not work.
The command `npm run s2` works correctly.
The command `git flow release start v1` works correctly.

```
npm run s1

> wsdl-xsd-parser@1.3.1 s1 C:\temp\temp2\wsdl-xsd-parser
> git flow release start v1

git: 'flow' is not a git command. See 'git --help'.

The most similar commands are
        reflog
        show
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! wsdl-xsd-parser@1.3.1 s1: `git flow release start v1`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the wsdl-xsd-parser@1.3.1 s1 script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.
```

The text of the error sometimes changes. For some unknown reason.

```
npm run s1

> wsdl-xsd-parser@1.3.1 s1 C:\temp\temp2\wsdl-xsd-parser
> git flow release start v1

C:\Program Files\Git\usr\bin\git-flow: line 47: uname: command not found
C:\Program Files\Git\usr\bin\git-flow: line 76: sed: command not found
C:\Program Files\Git\usr\bin\git-flow: line 76: dirname: command not found
C:\Program Files\Git\usr\bin\git-flow: line 115: /gitflow-shFlags: No such file or directory
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! wsdl-xsd-parser@1.3.1 s1: git flow release start v1
npm ERR! Exit status 1
```

Versions:

```
>npm -v  
6.1.0

>node -v  
v8.11.3

>git --version  
git version 2.18.0.windows.1
```

https://github.com/npm/npm/issues/21152

Comment: Odd. There should be little difference between running the command through npm scripts or not.

Comment: @evolutionxbox How to debug to find the cause of the problem?

Comment: Try creating a [mcve] of the issue. Create a blank npm project, edit the npm scripts, and try running the exact same command with and without npm.

Comment: @evolutionxbox I did. But the problem only plays on my computer.

Comment: Do you use [this project](https://github.com/khusamov/wsdl-xsd-parser) at all?

Comment: @evolutionxbox I design it. The problem is reproduced on my computer when this project is developed. And also in other projects.

Answer (score 0):

In the end, the problem was solved.
Added path to PATH C:\Program Files\Git\usr\bin
and started working...
and who is to blame? NPM or GIT???

And notice! Gitflow commands work without NPM